# Finding directions of the internal forces within a freely jointed rigid object?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, statics

Consider the the following problem:
[image]

Here is a force diagram showing the situation:
[image]

For part (i) Taking moments about $B$ for $BC$ gives

$84.5Lcos\beta=2LT$ So $T=39$N

For part (ii) Resolving vertically upwards on $BC$ gives

$39\cos\beta -84.5=-r$ which results in $r=48.5$N in the direction shown on diagram (downwards). I'm aware that the question asks for the forces acting *on* $BC$ so I deduced that by newtons third law $Y=48.5$N (upwards). Everything so far is correct but here's the problem:

To find the horizontal component I resolved leftward on $BC$ to obtain $p=39\sin\beta$
giving $p=15$N direction as shown in diagram (leftward). Again realizing that the question asks for forces *on* $BC$, by newtons third law $X=15$N (**rightward**):
Here's the official answer:

[image]

The marks-scheme is always correct. So could someone please kindly explain what I did wrong?

Comment: In statics, the point at which moments are taken does not matter, but if you switch the sense of the $x$ axis for example, you have to switch the sense of what a positive moment is also.

Comment: @ja72 whichever you like? makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (ii) force $p$ acts to the left. This is obvious from statics since $T$ acts to the right in order to have balance.

The diagrams has the assumed positive directions for $p$ and $r$ and it is confusing that the answer talks about $X$ and $Y$.

Using $\cos \beta = \frac{12}{13}$, $\sin \beta = \frac{5}{13} $ and $W=84.5\,{\rm N}$

$$ \left. \begin{aligned} 
  2 L T & = L W \cos \beta \\
  T \sin \beta & = p \\
  T \cos \beta - W &= r 
\end{aligned} \right\} \begin{aligned} 
  T &= \frac{W}{2} \cos\beta \\
  p & =\frac{W}{2} \cos\beta \sin\beta \\
  r & = \frac{W}{2} \cos\beta \cos\beta - W
\end{aligned} $$

which makes $p=15$ positive (and hence to the left) and $r=-48.5$ negative (and hence upwards).

Again from inspection you could have guessed the directions since the forces must oppose the tension $T$.

Comment: Yes the X and Y are just the marks-schemes way of putting the horizontal and vertical components. Do you agree with the their answer or mine?

Comment: I am looking at a more detailed answer now. I am trying to deduce if I have to use $\sin \beta = \sqrt{1-\cos^2\beta}$ or would in cancel out.

Comment: For clarity I have changed the q and t to X and Y

Comment: Okay thanks for the verification, so the mark-scheme answer really is wrong?

Comment: The question asks for forces acting on _BC_ at _B_ and hence looking for $p$ and $r$, not $X$ and $Y$. So the answer is correct.

Comment: Hmm i'm confused. Are you sure you got that right? It was my understanding that forces acting _on_ $BC$ must come from $AB$ and hence $X$ and $Y$ are the forces desired?

Comment: In your FBD the blue body has forces $p$ and $r$ applied to them. It is right there in front of you. $X$ and $Y$ are the reaction forces on _AB_.

Comment: If you where holding _BC_ (instead of the bar _AB_) then you would be pulling to the left and up to keep the equilibrium.